# lualatex on Mac module 'lualatexquotejobname.lua' not found error

Tags: luatex

I updated my TeXLive distribution with the TeXLive utility that comes with MacTeX. However, I cannot get lualatex to run. Regardless of the document, after calling `lualatex test.tex` (say) I get the error message:

```
 (./texsx.tex[\directlua]:1: module 'lualatexquotejobname.lua' not
 found: no field package.preload['lualatexquotejobname.lua'] [kpse lua
 searcher] file not found: 'lualatexquotejobname.lua' [kpse C searcher]
 file not found: 'lualatexquotejobname.lua' no file
 '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/lualatexquotejobname.so' no file
 '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so' no file
 './lualatexquotejobname.so' stack traceback: [C]: in function
 'require' [\directlua]:1: in main chunk. <everyjob> \directlua
 {require("lualatexquotejobname.lua")}
```

Unfortunately, I could not fix this with any of the posts found on this forum, or somewhere else. Am I missing something obvious? Has anybody a fix for this?

Comment: Do you need the standalone Lua app? (Version 5.2.x, right?) What happens if you uninstall it completely and then recompile your TeX document?

Comment: @Mico I don't need know anything about this app. Or are you saying I have to install something? And I have installed the whole texlive distribution from scratch. And the "missing" file is there:
$ kpsewhich lualatexquotejobname.lua
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/lualatexquotejobname.lua

Comment: I'm a MacTeX2017 user as well; separately, I also have Lua 5.3.4 on my system. For sure, though, my copy of LuaLaTeX never attempts to search for anything in `/usr/local/lib/lua/`. All I can surmise is that something went wrong in your MacTeX2017 installation. All I can suggest (sorry I wasn't clear enough before) is that you uninstall the standalone Lua app and then start over. Clearly, LuaLaTeX shouldn't be searching for `lualatexquotejobname.lua` anywhere below `/usr/local/lib/lua/`.

Comment: can you show the full log (including luatex startup banners) and also what is `which luatex` (or the mac equivalent) are you sure you are running the texlive 2017 luatex?

Comment: The instruction `\directlua{require("lualatexquotejobname.lua")}` is part of `\everyjob` in the `lualatex` format. It seems that `\directlua` is calling `/usr/local/bin/lua` instead of the embedded one, or that some environment variable is improperly set.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so much! I guess you found the reason: $which lualatex
/opt/local/bin/lualatex
$ which xelatex
/Library/TeX/texbin/xelatex
But there is a version of lualatex under /Library/TeX/texbin/ as well. I have never installed lualatex separately, so I dunno where the version in /opt/... comes from.

Comment: @egreg Seems like you're right.Thank you so much! When I compile with /Library/TeX/texbin/lualatex, everything works fine. Do you know by chance which environment variable this is?

Comment: @marmot Argh! You have something installed with MacPorts! I have long removed any trace of it from my machines.

Comment: @egreg How did you remove this properly? (If I remove the lualatex under /opt/... by hand, it just does  no longer get found.) (And I am not aware of having installed LaTeX related things with MacPorts, but of course it might have come with another tool.)

Comment: @marmot Tell MacPorts to uninstall `luatex`. Then, when you have some time, uninstall MacPorts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was solved by comments by David Carlisle and @egreg, whom I really wish to thank at this point. This post is just for the records, in case someone else runs into similar problems. Apparently, `lualatex` got installed by another package manager. In my case, there was a version under

```
/opt/local/bin/lualatex
```

After removing this version (and starting a new shell), the correct version

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/lualatex
```

gets invoked and the documents run through.