# Installing texstudio broke my latex distribution

Tags: texstudio, enumitem, mac, texshop

I installed `texstudio` to give it a try.

Before, I used to use `TexShop`. Since I have installed it, a MWE such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

doesn't compile anymore (with `TeXShop` or `texstudio`). The error message is

> /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/dblatex/misc/enumitem.sty:488:
>   LaTeX E rror: Unknown option `shortlabels' for package`enumitem'

NB: few days ago, I tried to install another software that installed another copy of latex through macports. But I think I uninstalled it, via macports also.

The path above with `dblatex` makes think of this. I remember during the installation to have seen this name.

Can you help?

Comment: Texstudio etc. are just editors that rely on the TeX installation. I don't expect them to change the installation of TeX. It is more likely that the TeX tree was screwed up by the additional installation of a LaTeX copy with macports.

Comment: Yes, but everything was ok, until I installed texstudio... What would you suggest to clean up my installation?

Comment: I am no Mac user, but a clear wiping of the TeX tree and reinstallation should be successful. But try a rehashing of the TeX database

Comment: It seems that latex chooses the wrong `enumitem.sty` file. How would suggest to deal with this issue? Is there a way to tell `pdflatex` to first check in `textlive` rather than in `texmf-local`?

Comment: I am a Mac user and believe @ChristianHupfer is right. I have made the same mistake before.

Comment: PS: `rehash` failed

Comment: Which error @marmot?

Comment: @Colas: If the wrong `enumitem.sty` file is found it is either a modified one or a very old one. `shortlabels` is an option of `enumitem` for at least 7 years, as far as I can remember. Has your TL (etc.) distributation aged that much? ;-) (Just checked: The latest release of `enumitem` is from 2011)

Comment: Using macports to install LaTeX on top of my TeXLive installation. Actually, I did not explicitly install TeX things, but somehow macports screwed up my lualatex directories. @egreg found this out.

Comment: @marmot: Your turn ;-) It is apparently the wrong setup caused by macports then and not the installation of the editor

Comment: Interesting... Since I don't want to break other things, I'm going now just to replace this old version of `enumitem` (it is `Python.framework`... why?!) by a new one. (edit: it worked)

Comment: To make @ChristianHupfer happy: you can read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408421/121799) how stupid I was. (And life is so much better with a working lualatex command ;-)

Comment: @marmot: I am not happy actually. It was just a guess

Comment: @marmot: Wait, you're a LuaLaTeX user? Oh noooooooooooooooo.... ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I was just kidding ;-) Didn't know what you mean by "It's your turn". But as I wrote, I think your suggestion is the best thing one can do in this situation. (Before erasing the old distribution, of course one has to make sure to copy all self-defined fonts from the old to the new directories.)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Only I if I use Ti*k*Z Feynman (which became very popular even though I personally like Feynmp better...)

Comment: @marmot: 'It's your turn' meant that you could provide more insight as being a Mac user. You did that already.... (Yes, a backup of the fonts is a good idea)

Comment: macports should not be installing anything into `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`. That's not to say it doesn't - I would believe pretty much anything of macports. But it definitely ought not be. If it really did, you need to tease apart what is in that tree, keeping anything you installed there and discarding the rest. Then update the database, ensure all traces of macports's install are gone and figure out how to stop macports doing the same thing next time. This probably means installing a dummy package to tell it the dependencies are satisfied. Otherwise, it will keep screwing up MacTeX.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments (faulty installation).